# Conflict in choosing the perfect index in MongoDB query optimizer

Tags: mongodb, indexing, optimization, sql-execution-plan

My problem is related to the query optimizer of MongoDB and how it picks the perfect index to use. I realized that under some conditions the optimizer doesn't pick the perfect existing index and rather continues using the one that is close enough.

Consider having a simple dataset like:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "f1", "type" : "food", "quantity" : 500 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "f2", "type" : "food", "quantity" : 100 }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "p1", "type" : "paper", "quantity" : 200 }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "p2", "type" : "paper", "quantity" : 150 }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "f3", "type" : "food", "quantity" : 300 }
{ "_id" : 6, "item" : "t1", "type" : "toys", "quantity" : 500 }
{ "_id" : 7, "item" : "a1", "type" : "apparel", "quantity" : 250 }
{ "_id" : 8, "item" : "a2", "type" : "apparel", "quantity" : 400 }
{ "_id" : 9, "item" : "t2", "type" : "toys", "quantity" : 50 }
{ "_id" : 10, "item" : "f4", "type" : "food", "quantity" : 75 }
```

and then want to issue a query as following:

```
db.inventory.find({"type": "food","quantity": {$gt: 50}})
```

I go ahead and create the following index:

```
db.inventory.ensureIndex({"quantity" : 1,  "type" : 1})
```

The statistics of cursor.explain() confirms that this index has the following performance: ( "n" : 4, "nscannedObjects" : 4, "nscanned" : 9). It scanned more indexes than the perfect matching number. Considering the fact that "type" is a higher selective attribute with an identified match, it is surely better to create the following index instead:

```
db.inventory.ensureIndex({ "type" : 1, "quantity" : 1})
```

The statistics also confirms that this index performs better: ("n" : 4, "nscannedObjects" : 4, "nscanned" : 4). Meaning the second index needs exactly scanning the same number of indexes as the matched documents.

However, I observed if I don't delete the first index, the query optimizer continues using the first index, although the better index is got created.

According to the documentation, every time a new index is created the query optimizer consider it to make the query plan, but I don't see this happening here.

Can anyone explain how the query optimizer really works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Considering the fact that "type" is a higher selective attribute

Index selectivity is a very important aspect, but in this case, note that you're using an equality query on type and a range query on quantity which is the more compelling reason to swap the order of indices, even if selectivity was lower.

> However, I observed if I don't delete the first index, the query optimizer continues using the first index, although the better index is got created. [...]

The MongoDB query optimizer is largely **statistical**. Unlike most SQL engines, MongoDB doesn't attempt to reason what could be a more or less efficient index. Instead, it simply runs different queries in parallel from time to time and remembers which one was faster. The faster strategy will then be used. From time to time, MongoDB will perform parallel queries again and re-evaluate the strategy.

One problem of this approach (and maybe the cause of the confusion) is that there's probably not a big difference with such a tiny dataset - it's often better to simply scan elements than to use *any* kind of index or search strategy if the data isn't large compared to the prefetch / page size / cache size and pipeline length. As a rule of thumb, simple lists of up to maybe 100 or even 1,000 elements often don't benefit from indexing at all.

Comment: Can you point any documentation about the behavior of MongoDB optimizer out to me?
You are right about the order recognition and the effectiveness of the indexes depending on the dataset size, but this was a simple example to show the problem. 
My idea was that for more complicated queries, if I get indexes wrong and then I create all close combination of the indexes, the optimizer will be clever enough to find the best among them. But with this behavior, I have to try them  one-by-one by myself.
And thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: The documentation contains lots of information: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/ http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-plan-cache/. Wildly creating indexes is usually a bad idea; wait for the queries to become slow, monitor using the embedded profiler and reason how to optimize those queries, or plan your data structure for easy querying in the first place (considering equality before range, selectivity, etc.). Generally speaking, don't measure code or dbs with too little data - jitter and overhead will dominate runtime. By analogy, don't optimize empty databases.

Comment: It is good to note that this is most likely caused by first come first serve rules within the optimiser which is causing a suboptimal index to win on a smaller number of documents whereas it would lose on a much large and more real number.

Answer (score 1):

Like for doing anything greater, designing indexes requires some forward thinking. The goal is:

- Efficiency - fast read / write operations
- Selectivity - minimize records scanning
- Other requirements - e.g. how are sorts handled?

Selectivity is the primary factor that determines how efficiently an index can be used. Ideally, the index enables us to select only those records required to complete the result set, without the need to scan a substantially larger number of index keys (or documents) in order to complete the query. Selectivity determines how many records any subsequent operations must work with. Fewer records means less execution time.

Think about what queries will be used most frequently by the application. Use `explain` command and specifically see the `executionStats`:

- `nReturned`
- `totalKeysExamined` - if the number of keys examined very large than the returned documents? We need some index to reduce it.

Look at `queryPlanner`, `rejectedPlans`. Look at `winningPlan` which shows the `keyPattern` which shows which keys needed to indexed. Whenever we see `stage:SORT`, it means that the key to sort is not part of the index or the database was not able to sort documents based on the sort order specified in the database. And needed to perform in-memory sort. If we add the key based on which the sort happens, we will see that the `winningPlan`'s' `stage` changes from `SORT` to `FETCH`. The keys in the index needs to be specified based on the range of the data for them. e.g.: the **class** will have lesser volume than **student**. Doing this needs us to have a trade-off. Although the `executionTimeMillis` will be very less but the `docsExamined` and `keysExamined` will be relatively a **little** large. But this trade-off is worth making.

There is also a way to force queries to use a particular index but this is ***not recommended to be a part of deployment***. The command in concern is the `.hint()` which can be chained after `find` or `sort` for sorting etc. It requires the actual index name or the shape of the index.

In general, when building compound indexes for:
 - **equality field**: field on which queries will perform an equality test
 - **sort field**: field on which queries will specify a sort
 - **range field**: field on which queries perform a range test

The following rules of thumb should we keep in mind:

- Equality fields before range fields
- Sort fields before range fields
- Equality fields before sort fields